# How to add scroll to a huge submenu, in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, scroll, submenu

I am working on a wordpress template and my client wants a lot of stuff on a submenu. So big that it disappears from the screen area. 
How can I add an automatic scroll in that submenu? 
Or at least to add some arrows.

Thank you in advance.
Vasco

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CSS. Try adding this to your theme's stylesheet:

```
.submenu {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```